# ApexCharts: Hide every nth label in chart

Tags: charts, apexcharts

I would like to hide some of the labels from my chart made with ApexCharts.js. I am coming from Frappé Charts, which has a feature called "continuity." It allows you to hide labels if they do not comfortably fit, because the chart is a timeseries chart.

My ApexChart looks like this:

[image]

I would like to remove many of the dates, but still have them appear in the tooltip. I was able to do this in Frappé Charts and it looked like this:

[image]

Here's my code for the Apex chart:

```js
        var options = {
            chart: {
                animations: { enabled: false },
                toolbar: { show: false },
                zoom: { enabled: false },
                
                type: 'line',
                height: 400,
                fontFamily: 'PT Sans'
            },
            stroke: {
                width: 2
            },
            theme: {
                monochrome: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: '#800000',
                    shadeTo: 'light',
                    shadeIntensity: 0.65
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'New Daily Cases',
                data: [2,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,7,1,1,1,8,0,11,2,9,8,21,17,28,24,20,38,39,36,21,10,49,45,44,52,74,31,29,43,28,39,58,30,47,50,31,28,79,39,54,55,33,42,39,41,52,25,30,37,26,30,35,42,64,46,25,35,45,56,45,64,34,34,32,40,65,56,64,55,37,61,51,70,81,76,64,71,61,56,52,106,108,104,33,57,82,71,67,68,63,71,32,70,65,98,52,72,87,66,85,90,47,164,123,180,119,85,66,122,65,155,191,129,144,175,224,234,240,128,99,141,131,215,228,198,152,126,201,92,137,286,139,236,238,153,170,106,61]
            }],
            labels: ['February 28','February 29','March 1','March 2','March 3','March 4','March 5','March 6','March 7','March 8','March 9','March 10','March 11','March 12','March 13','March 14','March 15','March 16','March 17','March 18','March 19','March 20','March 21','March 22','March 23','March 24','March 25','March 26','March 27','March 28','March 29','March 30','March 31','April 1','April 2','April 3','April 4','April 5','April 6','April 7','April 8','April 9','April 10','April 11','April 12','April 13','April 14','April 15','April 16','April 17','April 18','April 19','April 20','April 21','April 22','April 23','April 24','April 25','April 26','April 27','April 28','April 29','April 30','May 1','May 2','May 3','May 4','May 5','May 6','May 7','May 8','May 9','May 10','May 11','May 12','May 13','May 14','May 15','May 16','May 17','May 18','May 19','May 20','May 21','May 22','May 23','May 24','May 25','May 26','May 27','May 28','May 29','May 30','May 31','June 1','June 2','June 3','June 4','June 5','June 6','June 7','June 8','June 9','June 10','June 11','June 12','June 13','June 14','June 15','June 16','June 17','June 18','June 19','June 20','June 21','June 22','June 23','June 24','June 25','June 26','June 27','June 28','June 29','June 30','July 1','July 2','July 3','July 4','July 5','July 6','July 7','July 8','July 9','July 10','July 11','July 12','July 13','July 14','July 15','July 16','July 17','July 18','July 19','July 20','July 21','July 22','July 23','July 24'],
            xaxis: {
                tooltip: { enabled: false }
            },
        }

        var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);

        chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```

And here's my code for the Frappé Chart if it helps:

```js
        const data = {
            labels: ['February 28','February 29','March 1','March 2','March 3','March 4','March 5','March 6','March 7','March 8','March 9','March 10','March 11','March 12','March 13','March 14','March 15','March 16','March 17','March 18','March 19','March 20','March 21','March 22','March 23','March 24','March 25','March 26','March 27','March 28','March 29','March 30','March 31','April 1','April 2','April 3','April 4','April 5','April 6','April 7','April 8','April 9','April 10','April 11','April 12','April 13','April 14','April 15','April 16','April 17','April 18','April 19','April 20','April 21','April 22','April 23','April 24','April 25','April 26','April 27','April 28','April 29','April 30','May 1','May 2','May 3','May 4','May 5','May 6','May 7','May 8','May 9','May 10','May 11','May 12','May 13','May 14','May 15','May 16','May 17','May 18','May 19','May 20','May 21','May 22','May 23','May 24','May 25','May 26','May 27','May 28','May 29','May 30','May 31','June 1','June 2','June 3','June 4','June 5','June 6','June 7','June 8','June 9','June 10','June 11','June 12','June 13','June 14','June 15','June 16','June 17','June 18','June 19','June 20','June 21','June 22','June 23','June 24','June 25','June 26','June 27','June 28','June 29','June 30','July 1','July 2','July 3','July 4','July 5','July 6','July 7','July 8','July 9','July 10','July 11','July 12','July 13','July 14','July 15','July 16','July 17','July 18','July 19','July 20','July 21','July 22','July 23','July 24'],
            datasets: [{
                name: 'Cumulative Cases',
                values: [2,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,7,1,1,1,8,0,11,2,9,8,21,17,28,24,20,38,39,36,21,10,49,45,44,52,74,31,29,43,28,39,58,30,47,50,31,28,79,39,54,55,33,42,39,41,52,25,30,37,26,30,35,42,64,46,25,35,45,56,45,64,34,34,32,40,65,56,64,55,37,61,51,70,81,76,64,71,61,56,52,106,108,104,33,57,82,71,67,68,63,71,32,70,65,98,52,72,87,66,85,90,47,164,123,180,119,85,66,122,65,155,191,129,144,175,224,234,240,128,99,141,131,215,228,198,152,126,201,92,137,286,139,236,238,153,170,106,61],
                chartType: 'line'
            }]
        }

        const chart = new frappe.Chart('#chart', {
            data: data,
            type: 'line',
            height: 250,
            animate: false,
            barOptions: {
                spaceRatio: 0.25
            },
            colors: ['#800000'],
            tooltipOptions: {
                formatTooltipY: d => d.toLocaleString()
            },
            axisOptions: {
                xAxisMode: 'tick',
                xIsSeries: true
            },
            lineOptions: {
                hideDots: true,
                regionFill: true
            }
        })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/frappe-charts@1.5.2/dist/frappe-charts.min.iife.min.js"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```

I've tried using the `formatter` callback function to return only every 10th value, but things get all out of position and the tooltips don't work. I get similar problems returning an empty string or a space for the values I wish to exclude (but still include in the tooltip).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try 2 things.

```js
xaxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
}
```

You can convert the `x-axis` to datetime and labels will align as shown below
[image]

**Or**

You can stop rotation of the x-axis labels using

```js
xaxis: {
  labels: {
    rotate: 0
  }
}
```

which produces the following result.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this answer worked great! In case anyone else finds this, here's how I formatted the dates correctly. I inputted ISO 8601 dates, and added an option to the `xaxis` settings: `labels: { format: 'MMMM d' }`. [Here](https://apexcharts.com/docs/datetime/) is a list of more formats.

Answer (score 5):

What I do is calculate the ratio between the area's width and the number of ticks, and if that ratio is above a certain number, I add a *classname* to the chart or it's wrapper and there I write:

```css
.apexcharts-xaxis-label{
  display: none;
  &:nth-child(5n){ display:revert; }
}
```

So **every 5th** label is shown and the rest are hidden.
You can also set up a [resizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) to add/remove the special class.

This require the below config to be given to the chart:

```js
xaxis: {
  labels: {
    rotate: 0, // no need to rotate since hiding labels gives plenty of room
    hideOverlappingLabels: false  // all labels must be rendered
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Vsync answer have not worked for me. It needed a little modification:

```
.apexcharts-xaxis-texts-g text[id^='SvgjsText'] {
    display: none;
}
.apexcharts-xaxis-texts-g text[id^='SvgjsText']:nth-of-type(5n) {
    display: revert;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

labels: ['',this.props.itemNames], //"(labels: [the label , the label below])"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).